# End of selection based values for formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to do some excel analysis and for this my formula needs a variable input.

Normaly its input range should be `$A$1:$A[end]` but `$A[end]` needs to have another value, `$B[end]` added to it.

e.g. if the `end=3` then the formula would need to process the following values:

```
A1, A2 and (A3+B3)
```

is there some easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=sum(a1:index(a:a, match(1e99, a:a)), index(b:b, match(1e99, a:a)))
```

Note that `match(1e99, a:a)` is the last row in column A with a number. When referencing column B, you index B:B but use the same `match(1e99, a:a)` endpoint row number so the ranges remain the same size.